# Validate if duplicate record exist in database in rails 4

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have model Contact with fields f_name, m_name, l_name and xyz_id. I want to validate if same record (case insensitive) is present in database.

I tried following statement in model:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :f_name, scope: [:m_name, :l_name, :xyz_id], message: 'Contact already exist'
```

Above statement is able to validate case sensitively and my requirement is case insensitive validation. Any suggestion will be helpful for me. Thanks.

Example:
record1 - f_name: fname, l_name: lname, m_name: mname, xzy_id: 1
record2 - f_name: Fname, l_name: Lname, m_name: Mname, xzy_id: 1

So basically, system should not allow to add record2 as record1 and record2 have same data. Adding separate validation for each field to check case insensitive uniqueness will generate list of 4 error messages. I am aiming to show single message saying 'Contact already exist'

Comment: you can do Case Insensitive false e.g  validates_uniqueness_of :f_name, scope: [:m_name, :l_name, :xyz_id], message: 'Contact already exist',  :case_sensitive => false

Comment: adding case_sensitive: false will check case insensitive for f_name only. But for scope, it will perform case sensitive check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
validates_uniqueness_of :f_name, scope: [:m_name, :l_name, :xyz_id], message: 'Contact already exist', case_sensitive: false
```

For more information please refer to this [link.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of)